# -bash syntax error "fi"

Tags: bash, shell

I am try to create a symlink using ssh. Here the commands I am using.

```
cd /home
for homedir in *
do if [ -d ${homedir} ]
ln -s /etc/cpbackup-exclude.conf ${homedir}/cpbackup-exclude.conf
fi
done
```

After I enter fi I get this error. "-bash: syntax error near unexpected token 'fi'

I am not sure what is wrong?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Sorry I am new to ssh. What do you mean?

Comment: I think you are confusing `ssh` with `bash`. `ssh` is used to connect to a remote machine; `bash` is the command processor you interact with once logged in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax of the `if` command is:

```
if test-commands; then
  consequent-commands;
[elif more-test-commands; then
  more-consequents;]
[else alternate-consequents;]
fi
```

---

Add keyword `then` to your code:

```
if [ -d ${homedir} ]
then
    ln -s /etc/cpbackup-exclude.conf ${homedir}/cpbackup-exclude.conf
fi
```

BTW, you can indent your code to make it easy to read.

Comment: Thank you. 
Now I am getting this error: bash: In: command not found

Comment: @BostonBB: You must have messed up your `$PATH` somehow. We don't have enough information to know how that happened. `ln` is a fundamental command, and it should be available in `/bin` and/or `/usr/bin`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might need the keyword `then` after condition in the if statement.

See documentation [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html).